# Xamarin forms Rest Client

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms, client

Anybody suggest me a good Rest client that i can use for my xamarin forms cross platform application ?

(Android and Windows Phone)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very open question.

Anyway my favorite:

[Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit)

**Updated** Removing the other two libraries that even though you can do REST with them they are not considered REST clients but HTTP clients.

Comment: I wouldn't call these REST clients, except for Refit. ModernHttpClient and HttpClient are just as their name indicates HTTP clients to make calls to any HTTP service on the Internet, not limited to RESTful services.

Comment: You are right, not limited to RESTful but they do RESTful as well so shouldn't they count as REST client for this?

Comment: OP is looking for a "good Rest client". I would argue a HTTP client does not fulfill that (opinion based), because it does not help making it easy to call a RESTful API. It just provides the transport.

Answer (score 1):

You can you **[Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/)**.

Then, you define a **RestService** class that contains a **HttpClient** instance:

```
public class RestService : IRestService
{
    HttpClient client;

    public RestService()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    }

    // example for GET request
    public async Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri); // make a GET request
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // handle response here
        }
    }
}
```

You should follow this article:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there are simple implementation for this purpose but you have to write your own parsers, senders, receivers according to your needs. I would give you a little example :) First of all i have a base class for my generic restCall

```
public abstract class BaseDto
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

than write your business objects like

```
public class UserDto : BaseDto
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
   //etc.
}
public class SavedUserDto : BaseDto
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
   //etc.
}
```

than write a simple http caller

```
public string Post<T>(string url, T entity) where T : BaseDto
{
   //here u will write a HttpClient and send receive json. U can find examples on the net. Of course use Newtonsoft for json convertions
}
```

Than write a generic method to call this post method, of course you will send a baseDto and receive a baseDto too :)

```
public K Call<T, K>(
        string restApiPath,
        T entity) where T : BaseDto where K : BaseDto
{
   var response = Post(restApiPath, entity);
   //you can handle errors, auth faults etc. here.
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<K>(response);
}
```

than in your code just do

```
var savedUser = Call<UserDto,SavedUserDto>("127.0.0.1/user/save",new UserDto{Name="John"})
```

Hope it can give you an idea. Than when you add a new service method on your rest api, you can call it just with a single line of code (of course you have to write new business DTO's - aka data transfer objects:))

Of course all this POST and CALL methods on different classes. Do not forget, a class must do only one thing. So POST method owner class (let's call it HttpCaller) will only send the Dto to the server and get the answer. CALL method owner class (lets call it MyService) will get the resut and process it etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient. It is good. get from nuget System.Http.Net